# Parse dict of dicts to string

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have a dictionary with following structure :

`{1: {'message': u'test', 'user': u'user1'},
 2: {'message': u'test2', 'user': u'user2'}}`

I'd like to create a string containing values from the inner dictionary in this form :

```
string = "<span>test1</span><span>user1</span><br />
          <span>test2</span>..."
```

I've tried everything from `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()`, `(k,v) for k, v in dict` but I cannot make it work. What is the proper way ?

Comment: your example output shows the keys, not the values

Comment: I don't understand why you just don't use a list of dictionaries? If the keys of the outer dictionary are just increasing numbers, then you're better off making them a list. Also remember that you're not guaranteed the order of retrieval when fetching `dict.keys()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> d={1: {'message': u'test', 'user': u'user1'}, 2: {'message': u'test2', 'user': u'user2'}}

>>> ''.join('<span>%(message)s</span><span>%(user)s</span><br/>' % v for k,v in sorted(d.items()))
u'<span>test</span><span>user1</span><br/><span>test2</span><span>user2</span><br/>'
```

Comment: It's better to iterate over sorted(d.items()) to preserve right order.

Comment: @Habbie: haha, yes I suppose so :).  @Leonid Shvechikov: Good catch.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
dod = {1: {'message': u'test', 'user': u'user1'}, 2: {'message': u'test2', 'user': u'user2'}}
string = ""
for v in dod.values():
    string = string + "<span>"+v['message'] + "</span><span>" + v['user'] + "</span><br />\n"
```

Or, in much better python style

```
string = '\n'.join( ("<span>"+v['message'] + "</span><span>" + v['user'] + "</span><br />" for v in dod.values()) )
```

If you need the users sorted, you could have

```
ksorted = sort(dod.keys())
for k in ksorted:
    v = dod[k]
    string = string + "<span>"+v['message'] + "</span><span>" + v['user'] + "</span><br />\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {1: {'message': u'test', 'user': u'user1'}, 2: {'message': u'test2', 'user': u'user2'}}
strg = "".join(["<span>%s</span><span>%s</span><br />" % (item['message'], item['user']) for item in x.values()])
print strg
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
>>> d={1: {'message': u'test', 'user': u'user1'}, 2: {'message': u'test2', 'user': u'user2'}}
>>> l=[]
>>> for k,v in d.iteritems():
...     l.append('%s%s%s' % ('<span>', '</span><span>'.join(v.values()),'</span>'))
... 
>>> print '<br/>\n'.join(l)
<span>test</span><span>user1</span><br/>
<span>test2</span><span>user2</span>
```